# Selenium tests run on local machine but not through jenkins

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins

When running Selenium tests with C# in Visual Studio on my local machine the tests run fine and all pass. However when I try to run them on jenkins they fail. If I use FireFox then Jenkins runs fine. The problem with that though is that my boss wants to use IE because that's what our company uses most.

Here is the code that is failing to run:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void openBrowser()
{
    //Start Opening browser

    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
    {
        InitialBrowserUrl = baseURL,
        IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
        IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
        EnableNativeEvents = false
    };

    string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\Users\eedward7\Desktop\Selenium";

    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);    
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.baseURL);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_UserName")));
    driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_UserName").SendKeys(userID);
    driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_Password").SendKeys(password);

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton")));
    driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton").Click();
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("ctl00_TreeView1t6")));
}
```

Here is the Jenkins error message:

> Initialization method Selenium.Tests.openBrowser threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:61076/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.

And Last but not least the Stacktrace:

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver..ctor(String internetExplorerDriverServerDirectory, InternetExplorerOptions options)
>      at Selenium.Tests.openBrowser() in c:\Users\eedward7\Desktop\Selenium\Selenium\UnitTest1.cs:line 50

If anyone has any suggestions that would be amazing because I am at a loss right now on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try chromeDriver with these options

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("test-type");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: NB  : The default installation runs windows service with "local system" account, which does not seem to have enough priveleges to execute, so You could try running Jenkins service with account with good privilige